# Importing Select2 & Laravel Vite

Tags: import, jquery-select2, vite

I'm trying to use [select2](https://select2.org/) in my Laravel 10 project, which is using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/). I kept getting the error

```
    Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function
```

**My question:**

> What is the correct way to import select2 in Vite (without having to
> use a Vite config alias)? What am I doing wrong?

I've run `npm i select2` (from my package.json)

```
    "select2": "^4.1.0-rc.0",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
```

I've tried a bunch of different ways of importing but landed on

1. updating my vite.config.js file (simplified for example)

   ```
    import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
    import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
    import path from 'path';

    export default defineConfig({
        plugins: [
            laravel({
                input: ['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'],
                refresh: true,
            }),
        ],
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                'select2': 'node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js',

            }
        },
    });
   ```
2. using the following in my app.js

   ```
    import 'select2';
    import '../../node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.css';
   ```

The weird thing is

1. `select2` is working
2. I get a console log error: Failed to load url `/@fs/node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js (resolved id: /node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js? [...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it working without alias, follow these steps:

1. Install **jquery** and **select2**:

```
npm i jquery select2 --save-dev
```

2. Edit **bootstrap.js** for referencing **jquery** and **select2**

```js
// import jquery and select2
import $ from "jquery";
import select2 from 'select2';
window.$ = $; // <-- jquery must be set
select2(); // <-- select2 must be called
```

3. Import **select2 CSS** in **app.js**

```js
//-- Select2
import "/node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.css";
//--
import '../css/app.css';
// ...
```

Now you can use it in your components:

```js
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
```

[image: select2 rendering example]